# Read a CSV file from S3 using Trino

Tags: amazon-s3, trino

Scenario:

I upload a CSV file into a S3 bucket and now I would like to read this table using Trino.

Is it possible to just read the table without the CREATE TABLE statement? Maybe simple SELECT only? Or I have to CREATE TABLE everytime I want to read the CSV file?